# WinUSB createFile succes but WinUSBInitialize failed

Tags: winusb

I followed the guide of 'How to access the USB Device'
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540174.aspx

```
//Open the device 

//lpDevicePath is '\\?\usb#vid_4255&pid_1000#123456789abc#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}'

*hDeviceHandle = CreateFile (
    lpDevicePath,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);
```

After this step, `*hDeviceHandle` is not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

Then, I called `WinUsb_Initialize(hDeviceHandle, phWinUSBHandle)` but it returns error 50, does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If your hDeviceHandle is a `HANDLE*` type you should call `WinUsb_Initialize` like this:

```
WinUsb_Initialize(*hDeviceHandle, phWinUSBHandle)
```